# 'RLMException', reason: 'Table has no columns'

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-ios

I have checked the related article with this problem. 
[Issue in adding data in Realm in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005270/issue-in-adding-data-in-realm-in-ios)

It seems only issue the previous post that folks were not adding dynamic to variables. that is not my case. I am not finding any other reason at all why it would fail.

> Build target 12.2, swift version: Swift 5, realm version: swift-10.2.1

my class:

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var name = "" 
}
```

This is how I am trying to add to the realm

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let person = Person()
    person.name = "John Doe"
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(person)
    }
```

Any pointers or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks a lot for reading the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need the [@objc](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objc-attribute) attribute in your variables. Also see [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#models).

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name = "" 
}
```

EDIT:

For completeness, Realm Object classes can be marked as @objcMembers (Swift 4+) which will make all class properties marked with *dynamic* to be managed by Realm. [See Property Attributes](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes) in the Swift guide.

Comment: Thanks @josh, not sure how did I miss it. It was the problem.

Comment: @Alix Be sure to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if is provided a solution so it can help others.

Comment: I would also like to add that *Note that if the class is declared as @objcMembers (Swift 4 or later), the individual properties can just be declared as dynamic var.* I've overlooked that several times when I see a class that just has *dymamic* in front of the vars. Keeping in mind that using *@objcMembers* will make all members with the dynamic keyword managed by Realm, which may not fit all use cases.